# Error when uploading code to an wifi lora board

Tags: arduino

When I try to upload code to my board, I get this error:
exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH
Error compiling for board WiFi LoRa 32.

How do I fix this? (I'm on mac 12.4.)

Answer (score 0):

This Error means That python is Ethier, not installed, or is not in The PATH variable, to fix this try installing python if you are using a Linux machine then follow the instructions on the python website.